# What should be changed about this Xpath line to verify dynamic list elements are loaded with WebDriverWait?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Initially, the `li`’s were being accessed like this:

```
dropDown.click()
sleep(2)
dropDownList = dropDown.find_element_by_tag_name('ul').find_elements_by_css_selector('li')
```

To replace time.sleep(), Xpath with WebDriverWait is used to access the last list item (to verify all `li`’s are loaded), but a timeout occurs.

What, if anything, should be changed about the following Xpath line to access the `ul` and last `li` in the following statement? If it helps, the `ul` is the only one in the dropDown element

```
path = ‘//div[@id = ' + dropDown.get_attribute('id') + ']/ul/li[last()]’
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, path))
dropDown.find_element_by_tag_name('ul').find_elements_by_css_selector('li')
```

Comment: You could wait for the presence of  a certain  li

Comment: You mean, (ii) a certain `li` element which contains a certain text? Or (ii) those elements occur after a while page fully loads? | Further information required...

Comment: The whole page shouldn't need to load. The 'ul' element isn't dynamically loaded, so the wait should only need to occur when the drop down list is clicked. All 'li' elements need to be loaded since the entire list of them is retrieved at once.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, could you indicate how to do this for list items of a specific ul element? For instance, I would need to avoid finding a loaded li element of a different list.

Comment: @Philip,  do you have an example?

Comment: @Phillip You have to identify the UL that you want. You can use id, class, or any properties of the UL such as display, text.

Comment: @Buaban To clarify, each UL is identified. If it helps, there is a common identifier for all LIs in the list.

Comment: what about waiting for last li like //specific ul/li[last()]

Comment: @murali selenium trainer Can Xpath access the `ul` in the following way (there is only one `ul` in the dropDown element)? `//div[@id = ' + dropDown.get_attribute('id') + ']/ul/li[last()]`.

Comment: Yes, in java i used like this Sting myid=dropDown.get_attribute('id'); String myxpath="//div[@id = " +  myid + "]/ul/li[last()]" . Only thing is i used double quotes as per Java, try similarly in python.

Comment: @murali selenium trainer apparently that line didn't work. I tried clicking the drop down list and using WebDriverWait with Xpath '//div[@id = ' + dropDown.get_attribute('id') + ']/ul/li[last()]' but there was a timeout